# Cannot configure table-per-hierarchy in configuration classes

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I am trying to get EF Core 8.0.2's table-per-hierarchy working, with this simple program:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using var context = new TestDbContext();
await context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var items = await context.Items.OfType<ConcreteItemA>().ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} {item.Number:C2}");
}

public enum BaseItemType
{
    ConcreteA = 0,
    ConcreteB = 1
}

public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BaseItemType Type { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItemA : BaseItem
{
    public ConcreteItemA()
    {
        Type = BaseItemType.ConcreteA;
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItemB : BaseItem
{
    public ConcreteItemB()
    {
        Type = BaseItemType.ConcreteB;
    }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseItem> Items => Set<BaseItem>();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlite()
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Debug)
            .EnableDetailedErrors();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

The entities are configured using these configuration classes:

```
public abstract class BaseItemTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseItem
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Items")
            .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Type)
            .HasValue<ConcreteItemB>(BaseItemType.ConcreteB)
            .HasValue<ConcreteItemA>(BaseItemType.ConcreteA)
            .IsComplete();

        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder.Property(b => b.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(b => b.Name).IsRequired();

        ConfigureSubType(builder);
    }

    protected abstract void ConfigureSubType(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder);
}

public class ConcreteItemATypeConfiguration : BaseItemTypeConfiguration<ConcreteItemA>
{
    protected override void ConfigureSubType(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteItemA> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Number).HasDefaultValue(42);
        builder.HasData(new ConcreteItemA { Name = "A", Number = 41 });
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemBTypeConfiguration : BaseItemTypeConfiguration<ConcreteItemB>
{
    protected override void ConfigureSubType(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteItemB> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).HasDefaultValue(42.0M);
        builder.HasData(new ConcreteItemB { Name = "B", Amount = 41.0M });
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Cannot
> configure the discriminator value for entity type 'ConcreteItemB'
> because it doesn't derive from 'ConcreteItemA'.' was thrown while
> attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported
> at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Is it not possible to do all configuration through the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`? Do I need to put some of it into the `OnModelCreating`, and if so, which parts?

Comment: This is definitely not a *simple* example - the model configuration is placed in separate configuration classes, probably to enable migrations. It's easier to solve problems if you isolate them to their parts. Try with an actually simple example first, like the [example in the Inheritance docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration). TPH is the default so no extra code is needed in the simplest case. 1 extra line is needed to specify a discriminator column and 2 more to specify extra discriminator values.

Comment: Add configuration classes only *after* you get the simple example to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code won't work as you expect:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Items")
        .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Type)
        .HasValue<ConcreteItemB>(BaseItemType.ConcreteB)
        .HasValue<ConcreteItemA>(BaseItemType.ConcreteA)
        .IsComplete();

    builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

    builder.Property(b => b.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.Property(b => b.Name).IsRequired();

    ConfigureSubType(builder);
}
```

As a base class for the entity type config, that is going to get called for both concrete types, filling in for `TEntity`. What you likely need to do is update the signature to:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Item> builder)
```

But you don't want it part of a base class entity type configuration, just an `IEntityTypeConfiguration<Item>`, non-inherited.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out why my solution wasn't working; I'd somehow forgotten that the base class was going to get invoked for each sub-type. It's nice to know EF Core is capable of working out my intention for the hierarchy with a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too much generics lunacy, I recommend writing the configurations as such:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

using var context = new TestDbContext();
await context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var itemsA = await context.Items.OfType<ConcreteItemA>().ToListAsync();
var itemsB = await context.Items.OfType<ConcreteItemB>().ToListAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Items of type A:");
foreach (var item in itemsA)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} {item.Number}");
}
Console.WriteLine("Items of type B:");
foreach (var item in itemsB)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} {item.Amount}");
}

public enum BaseItemType
{
    ConcreteA = 0,
    ConcreteB = 1
}

public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BaseItemType Type { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItemA : BaseItem
{
    public ConcreteItemA()
    {
        Type = BaseItemType.ConcreteA;
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItemB : BaseItem
{
    public ConcreteItemB()
    {
        Type = BaseItemType.ConcreteB;
    }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseItem> Items => Set<BaseItem>();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseInMemoryDatabase("test");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

The configuration classes change to this:

```
public abstract class BaseItemTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BaseItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BaseItem> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Items")
            .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Type)
            .HasValue<ConcreteItemB>(BaseItemType.ConcreteB)
            .HasValue<ConcreteItemA>(BaseItemType.ConcreteA)
            .IsComplete();

        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder.Property(b => b.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(b => b.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemATypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ConcreteItemA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteItemA> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Number).HasDefaultValue(42);
        builder.HasData(new ConcreteItemA() { Name = "A", Number = 41, Id = 1 });
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemBTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ConcreteItemB>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteItemB> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).HasDefaultValue(42.0M);
        builder.HasData(new ConcreteItemB() { Name = "B", Amount = 42.0M, Id = 2 });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "too much generics lunacy" is a very fair summary of my problem :-) your suggested change does indeed resolve the issue.